# How to set a <h:selectOneRadio> with no default value

Tags: jsf

i want to show selectOneRadio without a default value, forcing the user to choose one of the options. I'm using Boolean object set to NULL in bean, since boolean primitive type can't be null. But always the FALSE option are checked when the page shows up. I already reserach a lot here in stackoverflow, but all questions is to how set a default value, the opposit of what i want. I'm using JSF 1.2

Please, someone can help?

**VIEW**

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="example"
                  value="#{bean.booleanExample}"
                  layout="spread">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Do this" itemValue="#{false}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Do that" itemValue="#{true}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

**BEAN**

```
private Boolean booleanExample = null;

public Boolean getBooleanExample() {
    return booleanExample;
}

public void setBooleanExample(Boolean booleanExample) {
    this.booleanExample = booleanExample;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `private Boolean booleanExample` for this case, consider use type `int`, you will have 3 or more than 3 states as you want.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code for this tip and worked.